# iOSでwifiのon, offを切り替える

Tags: ios, swift

iOS Appでwifiのon, offを切り替えることはできますか?

例えば、AM9:00~PM9:00まではwifiをonにして、それ以外の時間帯ではoffにする
といったことをしたいのですが可能でしょうか?

Answer (score 2):

残念ながらiOSではアプリからWi-FiのON/OFFを切り替えることはできません。

アプリから設定アプリの各画面を開くことはできますが、直接値を変えることはできません。

参考:
[設定アプリの各画面に一発で遷移するURLスキームを使ってSafariの検索エンジン設定画面を開いてみる](http://qiita.com/tochiba/items/2794dd1c9d2523276e61)